# How to dynamically update react-json-schema form for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, react-jsonschema-forms

I have code something like this

```
const Jschema = {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Create Form",
    "required": [
        "level1",
        "level2"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "level1": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Level 1",
            "default": ""
        },
        "level2": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "enum": [
                  "no position"
              ],
              "type": "string"
          },
          "title": "Level 2",
          "uniqueItems": true
        },
    },
    "description": "Create Form"
  }

  const uiSchema = {
    "ui:order": [
        "level1",
        "level2"
    ],

    "level1": {
        "ui:title": "Rank Level 1",
        "ui:widget": "dropdown",
        "ui:placeholder": "Please select rank level 1"
    },
    "level2": {
      "ui:title": "Rank Level 2",
      "ui:widget": "checkboxes",
      "ui:placeholder": "Please select rank level 2"
    }
  }

  const dropDownList = {
    level1: {
      url: '/v2/level1_rank',
      name: 'level1',
      accessorName: 'level1_name',
      accessorValue: 'level1_value'
    }
  }
```

then will be generate on

```
render((
    <Form schema={schema}
          uiSchema={uiSchema}
          formData={formData} />
  ), document.getElementById("app"));
```

then I have some logic like this, the level1 (select dropdown) will be show position of board (CEO, CFO, CMO and CTO)
if we choose CFO level2 (checkboxes) will change to be (Accounting Manager, Finance Manager, Fraud Manager), if we choose CTO level2 will change to be (IT Manager, Infra Manager etc). let say I have backend and the backend was generate to state. I just get the state and need update the "items:" on level2 checkboxes.

So my question is how to change the "items:" on level2 by dynamically when I choose the level1
In my case, I want to select CFO, the the level2 checkbox will show three of position (Accounting Manager, Finance Manager, Fraud Manager etc) in CFO department, then I choose Accounting Manager and Fraud Manager only.

Thank you

Comment: Did u find a solution for this @Kyoo

Answer (score 0):

#### Individual input

In order to achieve this conditional field effect, normally it can be done via separate inputs.

```
  <Input name="input1" value={value1} onChange={onChange1} />
  <Input name="input2" value={value2} onChange={onChange2} />
```

Assuming both inputs are controlled via `value` and `onChange`, then you could wire with your own logic as

```
  const onChange1 = e => {
    if (e.target.value === '1') {
      value2 = '2'
    }
  }
```

#### Form handling

The above is assuming you have individual control. But if have a `Form` or `useForm`, you can still make it happen if you have access to the form `values` and `setValues`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (values.input1 === 1) {
      setValues({ input2: 2 })
    }
  }, [values])
```

Comment: this mean we are not using <Form from react-json-schema right?

Comment: You can read documentation of this `Form` to see how to set (or provided) `value` and `setValues`. Because whoever write that library they have to expose those two interfaces.

Comment: the doc only show by hardcode

```
"multipleChoicesList": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "A multiple choices list",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "foo",
          "bar",
          "fuzz",
          "qux"
        ]
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
```

That's why I confused 
:)

Comment: i see you have `formData`, what is that ? this to me might be `values`. What is the name of this component `Form` from which library ?

Comment: formData is standard from react-json-schema